# $p_t+2x^2tp_x=0$ with initial condition $p(x,0)=p_0(x)=\cos x$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The problem I'm asking about is

$p_t+2x^2tp_x=0$

with initial conditions $p(x,0)=p_0(x)=\cos x$ .

The characteristic curve can be found by separability to be $x=-\dfrac{1}{t^2+c}$ .

Solving for $c$ , we get $t^2+c=-\dfrac{1}{x}\Rightarrow c=-\dfrac{1}{x}-t^2$ .

If I am not mistaken, this means the general solution is $p(x,t)=f\left(-\dfrac{1}{x}-t^2\right)$ . Intuitively, I would think that $p(x,0)=f\left(-\dfrac{1}{x}\right)=\cos x$ . Does this mean the answer is $\cos\left(\left(\dfrac{1}{x}+t^2\right)^{-1}\right)$ ?

I'm finding it rather difficult to find good problem banks with solutions for some rudimentary partial differential equation problems in order that I can work out the general procedures with confidence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$$
{\rm p}\pars{x,t} = \fermi\pars{{1 \over x} + t^{2}}\,,\quad
{\rm p}\pars{x,0} = \fermi\pars{1 \over x} = \cos\pars{x} =
\cos\pars{1 \over 1/x}
$$
Then, $\fermi\pars{x} = \cos\pars{1/x}$:
$$\color{#0000ff}{\large%
{\rm p}\pars{x,t}} = \fermi\pars{1 + xt^{2} \over x} =
\color{#0000ff}{\large\cos\pars{x \over 1 + xt^{2}}}
$$
Let's check it:
\begin{align}
{\rm p}_{t}\pars{x,t} 
&=-\sin\pars{x \over 1 + xt^{2}}\bracks{-\,{2tx^{2} \over \pars{1 + xt^{2}}^{2}}}
=\sin\pars{x \over 1 + xt^{2}}{2x^{2}t \over \pars{1 + xt^{2}}^{2}}
\\[3mm]
2x^{2}t\ {\rm p}_{x}\pars{x,t} 
&=2x^{2}t\,\bracks{-\sin\pars{x \over 1 + xt^{2}}
{1 + xt^{2} - t^{2}x \over \pars{1 + xt^{2}}^{2}}}
=
-\sin\pars{x \over 1 + xt^{2}}
{2x^{2}t \over \pars{1 + xt^{2}}^{2}}
\end{align}